# Kubernetes ingress for leader follower system

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

I have a kubernetes service that works in a  leader/follower fashion, so only one of 2 pods (for HA)  can accept the connection. I want to make my service publicly available with traefik ingress controller.

One of the ways to achieve that - tweaks the readiness probe for the service, so slave pod will fail on readiness checks until it becomes a master. But I don't like this approach, because it will be confusing to distinguish if the pods are indeed failing, or just waiting to become a master?

Any thoughts are welcome

Answer (score 2):

So you don't need to use the k8s readiness probe for the traefik ingress, you can use a traefik backend health check defined in your k8s ingress through annotations. This way you don't forward to backends that are not active. For example:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: specific-deployment
  annotations:
    traefik.backend.healthcheck.port: 8080
    traefik.backend.healthcheck.scheme: http
    traefik.backend.healthcheck.path: /health   
spec:
  rules:
  - host: specific.minikube
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: stilton
          servicePort: http
```

This way you can use the k8s readiness probes for your pods.

Comment: Can't find in documentation https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/backends/kubernetes/ information regarding health check annotation? Does it works for you?

Comment: You are right they don't have it in the docs. imo it should be supported as its documented on other systems such as Docker and Marathon. If it isn't supported I'll open an Issue.

Comment: looks like you got your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275480/traefik-health-checks-via-kubernetes-annotation feel free to open a traefik issue on github. imo it should be there if you don't need the readiness probe.